# Proof that the generator of a Brownian transition semigroup is the Laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, brownian-motion

I am looking at the example below from Schilling's Brownian Motion. Here the generator of a Brownian transition semigroup is proven to be the Laplacian. What I don't understand from the proof below is the last part. Namely, why does the expression $|\partial_j \partial_k u(x+\theta B_t)-\partial_j \partial_k u(x)|^2$ converge to $0$ as $t \to 0$ uniformly in x? I don't see how to get this uniform convergence. 
Also, how do we use this to get, by dominated convergence, uniform convergence of $E[\frac{u(B_t +x)-u(x)}{t} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^d \partial_j^2 u(x)]$?

It seems like we can use dominated convergence theorem on $(\sum_{j,k=1}^d E(|\partial_j \partial_k u(x+\theta B_t) - \partial_j \partial_k u(x)|^2))^{1/2}$. But what we actually need to show is $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^d}(\sum_{j,k=1}^d E(|\partial_j \partial_k u(x+\theta B_t) - \partial_j \partial_k u(x)|^2))^{1/2} \to 0$ as $t \to 0$.  I do not know how to account for this supremum outside of this. I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that $\partial_j \partial_k u$ is uniformly continuous. This gives the uniform convergence of the expression.

Comment: @saz Can you explain a bit more please? I don't get why uniform continuity of a function $f$ implies uniform convergence in $x$ of $f(x+\theta B_t) \to f(x)$ as $t \to 0$.

Comment: You are telling me this 10 minutes after I wrote the comment... so you thought at most 10 minutes about this (... probably much less). Since the assertion is really a straight-forward consequence of the uniform continuity, I suggest that you take some more time to think about it. Take paper and pen and get your hands dirty.